# add data on Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I wanted to create a report about Parcels, their areas and their owners. 
I have 2 mdb data, first data is about parcels and their areas,
Second data is about their owners.

For example 
1. Data

```
345 parcel  32434 metre square                
343 parcel  1999  metre square                
342 parcel  2914  metre square
```

2.Data

```
345 parsel  owner1 surname1,
345 parcel  owner2 surname3,
345 parcel  owner3 surname3,
```

I mean a parcel has more than one owners.
I made relations about my mdb files. About parcels and their owner.
When I try to add owners on my report, there is onyl 1 owner on preview. Not more.
How can I solve my problem ?

Report has to be like that ;

345 parcel is 32434 metre square and owners are owner1 surname1, owner2 surname3,owner3 surname3

Answer (score 0):

Group the report by parcel first and in detail place

`areas owners`

Now write a formula to concatinate the areas and owners

```
Local StringVar a;
Local Stringvar b;

a=a+owners
b=b+areas
```

now in group footer place below line

`parcel + "is"+ a + " and "+ b`